# Best way to keep track of contributions / give "credit"

Tags: svn, redmine, redmine-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to give credit / keep track of contributions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401906/how-to-give-credit-keep-track-of-contributions)

We're using Redmine & SVN to manage a community project with lots of small code submissions. Starting to run into the problem of losing track of who coded what part, as often times code is added by someone other than the person who coded it, pulled from many places etc.

I'm looking for some interesting ideas to keep track of and give credit to various people for each commit.

This would need to be something not tied to the commit comment (as nearly 600 commits in this would be starting).

Is there anything similar to this currently in existence?

Comment: Good question, I'm really not particular. Any web based suggestions or starting points would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm committing the code I'll usually add a note in the commit logs like "Contributed by: John Doe, a_user, and Foo Bar".

For code that is already committed, I try to thank the people in the issue notes.

For historic commits like your 600 here, maybe you could just start a Wiki page in Redmine and put peoples names in there. Simple is usually best.

It's difficult to associate a specific piece of code with an author most times, especially as that code ages, moves around, and is refactored.