# How to give credit / keep track of contributions?

Tags: svn

We're using Redmine & SVN to manage a community project with lots of small code submissions. Starting to run into the problem of losing track of who coded what part, as often times code is added by someone other than the person who coded it & pulled from many places etc.

**I'm looking for some interesting ideas to keep track of and give credit to various people.**

This would need to be something not tied to the commit comment (as nearly 600 commits in this would be starting). But **hopefully some other Web based system**

Is there anything similar to this currently in existence? Spent a few hours on sourceforge to no avail.

**Edit:** We use SVN and are already nearing 600 revisions. I'd really like some web based system separate from the svn commit process but possibly pulls from the SVN. (I realize this would add "paperwork" so to speak, but it's worth it).

Comment: You could use SVN blame for offline info, but I guess you need something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations, an excellent problem to have. :)

The Linux kernel community has adopted a [Signed-off-by:](http://kerneltrap.org/node/3180) line in all patches intending to be integrated into the kernel. (There is even a command line option for [`git`](http://linux.yyz.us/git-howto.html#mbox) for adding the line when importing an mbox full of patches; something similar for you might be just the ticket.)

Comment: +1 if for nothing other than the first line. Every community project should be so lucky!

Comment: Thanks, it really is an awesome problem to have. 

Thanks again for this post, I hadn't heard of this and was a great read.

Unfortunately we use SVN and are already nearing 600 revisions. I'd really like some web based system separate from the svn commit process but possibly pulls from the SVN. (I realize this would add "paperwork" so to speak, but it's worth it).

Comment: @user664730, perhaps a "changes" file in your repository, that committers can use when making a new checkin, with the understanding that they say _who_ gave them the submission/idea/test case, etc?